# Regex with android

Tags: android, regex

I'm trying to apply regex in my android code to get a specific value from a HTML page. The HTML code is :

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Sometitle</title>
<body>
<span class="shout">VAL 32354</span>
</body>
</html>
```

my aim is to extract this text "VAL 32354" from the above mentioned HTML code ? I've searched long for regex with android and I found rare number of tutorials which were are all complicated for a beginner programmer like me . Any thoughts how to do that ? and thanks in advance

Note : if regex doesn't work in this case , what are the alternatives ?

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex. Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp. Have you tried using an XML parser instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1229023)

Comment: @raina77ow Well I do remember doing something similar with Regex in VB.NET few years ago and it worked

Comment: if it doesn't work with Android , what are the alternatives ?

Comment: Tell me, have you actually read the linked answer?

Comment: Well I read most of it , he's saying regex can't work with HTML etc..

Comment: @raina77ow: Please don't just link to that question without adding another link to an actual HTML parser library. That question by itself is basically useless.

Comment: Since when we should answer the questions by giving links? The answer is clear: stop using regex, find yourself an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Jsoup to parse the HTML?

See http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html

In this example, you could get the element with `Elements shoutList = doc.select("#shout");`

Comment: That's really a live saving answer =)